# Is "Xがどこに見つけられますか" an acceptable translation of "Where can I find X"?

Tags: translation, potential-form

I'm currently studying the potential form by making up sentences from several scenarios, and am finding it rather difficult to check their correctness using nothing but vague online translators.

Is the above translation acceptable? Here it is with some context:

```
すみませんが、どの[列]{れつ}に[食]{しょく}パンが[見]{み}つけられますか？
```

Or would it generally be better to form it in a simpler way, such as:

```
すみませんが、[食]{しょく}パンはどの[列]{れつ}にありますか？
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is far better... and it's good that you don't trust the online translators. :)

I'd recommend doing some Google searches of the verb(s) in question and kind of copying and pasting.  Other than that, it's going to be hard to know what verbs to use when w/o immersion.

Comment: Thanks, I guess you're right. I will try to frequent thesauri more often than simple translators and stick to the textbook definitions for now.